# Using jQuery UI Tabs. How would I make one of the tabs link to a URL rather than load a tab panel?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery UI tabs to create a vertical tab section of a page, and want the last vertical tab to link out to a URL rather than load a tab panel.

Any suggestions for the best way to do this? I can stick another element besides an LI into the list, but would rather have the last li just behave differently.

Thanks for any help.

Here's my javascript:

```
  // vtabs
  $("#aboutprod-tabs").tabs(
    { fx: [{opacity:'toggle', duration:'normal'},
    {opacity:'toggle', duration:'fast'}] })
    .addClass('ui-tabs-vertical');
```

And HTML

```
<div id="aboutprod-tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">3rd</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="/products">Learn more...</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    Tab panel 1
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    Tab panel 2  
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    Tab panel 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After your `.tabs()` call you can reverse the click behavior and `href` it changed, putting the `href` back like this:

```
$("li.last a").unbind('click').click(function() {
  this.href = $.data(this, 'href.tabs');​​​​
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZHXnG/).

**Update: Using newer versions of jQuery:**

There is no need to add a click handler once you unbind jQuery-UI's click handler from the link you want to change. This will work:

```
$("li.last a").unbind('click');
```

Comment: To make this work with jQuery 1.8.2/jQuery UI 1.9.0, just use `$("li.last a").unbind('click')`.  The example in the answer worked great for earlier versions of jQuery, but for some reason the added click handler was messing things up in the latest version.

Comment: Alex is absolutely correct, this answer should be edited to include this information.

Comment: I know this question is older but I thought this was an important note. If you are looking to go to an external link instead of just load one you need a click handler and it's working fine for me with jquery-ui-1.10.3. Instead of this.href, you replace it with Location.href. In my case I wanted to make a tab a logout button.

Comment: I couldn't get this code to work... I had to use:
`$("li:last a").unbind('click');`
To only affect the tab, I used:
`$('#tabID > ul > li:last a').unbind('click');`

Comment: Thanks- this helped out a lot. @JamesMoberg - I just gave the tab in question an id, such as <a id="mapLink" href="...">Site Map</a>. then all i needed was $("#mapLink").unbind('click');

Comment: Using jQuery UI 1.8.16, I had to change the added `click` event to instead use `each` to reassign the `href` from the data attribute, but then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the select method of the tabs:

`$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});`

and compare `ui.tab.id` (or `ui.panel.id`, based on the markup you are using) to the id of the tab you want to send, and use `location.href=...` to redirect the user.

Comment: where is this documented? http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ currently does not say anything about this for tabs...

Comment: This is something that may have been valid in 2010 when I wrote this, but I haven't kept up with jQuery, so I'm not sure. Good Luck.

Comment: thanks for the info, in the end I ended up making my own "tabs" little-script, because I also didn't want the styling, so I solved 2 problems in one **short** soulution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39621077/1835470