# jQuery UI tabs, have a tab link externally

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to get one of my jQuery UI tabs to link to an external url and not the tab contents. I have read similar posts on here, like this [Using jQuery UI Tabs. How would I make one of the tabs link to a URL rather than load a tab panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498064/using-jquery-ui-tabs-how-would-i-make-one-of-the-tabs-link-to-a-url-rather-than) with the same topic but becuase I know so little about how to code JQuery, I do not know how to implement it on my page to make it work.

My JQuery code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();

    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
      function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
      function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );

  });
</script>
```

HTML is this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Downloads</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="../../pics/youtube_logo.png" width="49" height="20"  alt=""/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'beforeActivate' event to handle the external URLs. here is an example.

```
$( "#tab" ).tabs({
  collapsible: true,
  active : false,
  beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
      if( $(ui.newTab).find('a').attr('href').indexOf('#') != 0 ){ //check if it is hash link
        window.open($(ui.newTab).find('a').attr('href'), '_self');
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to open the link in a new browser tab, make the target '_blank' instead of '_self', and add the line: return false; after the window.open

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to add an id to the tab

[HERES A JS FIDDLE DEMONSTRATING IT WORKING](http://jsfiddle.net/fdvtG/2/)

(Note, your hover event should just wrap those commands in one function like I'm doing.)

(Also note, I'm using window.open in my example whereas you should use window.location.  I had to do this because of same origin policy because jsfiddle uses frames)

```
<li><a id="fancy_tab"><img src="../../pics/youtube_logo.png" width="49" height="20"  alt=""/></a></li>
```

and then just add a click handler:

```
$('#fancy_tab').click(function(){
    window.location = "youtube.com";//hardcoded link but you could pull this from the tab
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't get it to work. html now looks like this" `<li><a id="fancy_tab" href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="../../pics/youtube_logo.png" width="49" height="20"  alt=""/></a></li> ` and jquery is this:     `$('#tabs').tabs();

    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
     function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); },
     function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );

   });
   
   $('#fancy_tab').click(function(){
    window.location = "youtube.com";//hardcoded link but you could pull this from the tab
});`

Comment: @Kim I'm not sure if you posted the full code, but there are unclosed brackets in what you just posted.  If thats just a segment, could you post a fiddle?  Its possible theres a stopPropagation somewhere

Comment: @Kim see my edited answer and working jsfiddle.  I made sure to include jquery library and jquery ui library in mine as you did not.